# Installing kernel modules in Android kernel

Tags: android, linux, android-source, netfilter, android-kernel

I am trying to develop a TCP traffic shaping solution with the help of netfilter hooks in linux kernel. Now I want to do the same in Android kernel. I used ubuntu and there I was able to install kernel module through insmod command. How to do the same in Android kernel. I have downloaded and build a android kernel and can run it on emulator. I am confused with the changed file system in Android kernel. Can anyone help me with installing kernel modules in Android kernel.

Comment: probably u better look in google-groups there's a specific group for android platform development i think there's even one for knerel development, or XDA-developpers which do it quite a lot.
for my knowledge it's problematic since the kernel code is a bit different for different devices(though each manufacture has to open their code!) most likely you need to compile the module as built in function and not a module since i;m not sure regarding insmod being part of android set of tools.

Comment: @codeScriber I think SO is also a good place to ask these questions. It's easier to look for questions here, and you can clearly assess the impact of the question. The only problem that there are not enough professionals in this topic here. But I think this situation will change soon.

Answer (score 1):

Even though loadable kernel modules (added through `insmod` command) are a convenient way to extend a running kernel, or perhaps because of this fact, some Android devices are not compiled with loadable module support. You can determine if a running kernel supports loadable modules by checking for the `modules` entry in the `proc` file system or looking for the value of `CONFIG_MODULES` in the kernel configuration. During the release of Android 4.3, Google disabled loadable module support for all supported Nexus devices. New kernel building is needed to enable LKM support, or you can add your module as a part of a kernel (built in) and build it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at the iptables, then you should know that they are already integrated into Android. You can read [this](http://randomizedsort.blogspot.com/2011/03/porting-iptables-1410-to-android.html) article to know how to install newer version.